# json compressor to one row

Tags: javascript, json, compression, phantomjs

i have a json-file from phantomjs, it look like this

```
{
            "startedDateTime": "2015-04-27T12:48:47.107Z",
            "time": 281,
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "url": "http://www.example.com/DE/de/shop/welcome.html;jsessionid=FEA0923A36729B5D6274597B4B59365E.appserver06t1",
                "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
                "cookies": [],
                "headers": [
                    {
                        "name": "User-Agent",
                        "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.8 Safari/534.34"
                    },.....
```

and i want compress that with javascript in one row like

```
{"startedDateTime": "2015-04-27T12:48:47.107Z","time": 281,"request": {"method": "GET","url": "http://www...........
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Replace all `\r\n` with an empty string?

Comment: Is this a file on the system returned by phantomJS or is it created from an object in PhantomJS? If the object is created in phantomJS I'd be curious how the JSON string is generated since JSON.stringify will remove \r\n by default. If it's a file on the system, I would not do this in phantomJS at request time, and instead remove them in a file editor.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you got that JSON file from PhantomJS, where do you want to use it? Or perhaps you want to minify it with PhantomJS in which case, you should show how you're currently print/return it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to integrate it into your build process then you could use this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-minify

or this:
https://github.com/shama/grunt-minjson